# set drop down value of second box depending on selection of first drop down

Tags: java, jquery, html

I have 2 drop downs declared as follows:

```
    <label for="select-choice-1" class="select">Customer Product Name</label>
    <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1" onchange="selectTransport(this.value)">
        <option value="a">Polyvinyl Chloride</option>
        <option value="b">Thermosetting</option>
        <option value="c">Thermoplastic</option>
    </select>
    <label for="select-choice-2" class="select">SABIC Product ID</label>
    <select name="select-choice-2" id="select-choice-2">
        <option value="A">1731-Black</option>
        <option value="B">1731-Brown</option>
        <option value="C">2345-Blue</option>
    </select>
       //js function
function selectTransport(value){
    if(value==="Thermoplastic")
    {

       var theText = "2345-Blue";
$("#select-choice-2 option:contains(" + theText + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');


    }}
```

Somehow  the second drop down is not being selected using this.How can I automatically select the value on the second drop down after the first drop down value has been selected, using a jquery function?

Comment: both select has same id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 $(function(){
   $('#select-choice-1').change(function(){
      var sel = $(this).val();
      $('#select-choice-2').val(sel.toUpperCase());
   });
 });
```

**Update**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/uHmqu/)**

```
function selectTransport(value){
//value return a,b,c
var val = $('#select-choice-1 [value="'+value+'"]').html();//.text()
  if(val==="Thermoplastic"){alert('test');
    var theText = "2345-Blue";
    $("#select-choice-2 option:contains(" + theText + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question and added and what i am trying and that it is not working .

Comment: Hi Pragnesh, what your code does is it highlights 2345-blue in the second drop down when i go to see the list but it doesnt show the value 2345-blue in the box .

Comment: .Yes i did see the code on fiddle and it is working fine but i am working on icenium and there the drop down item is being selected and not being displayed .So do i have to refresh the drop down or something?

Comment: @user2185012, please check there may be some error/issue in html or code

Comment: ,the code runs fine on fiddle but on icenium in the if loop of the function you suggested if i add  $("#select-choice-2").selectmenu("refresh"); then it is reflecting the change. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

```
function selectTransport(value){
 if(value==="Thermoplastic")
 {

    var theText = "2345-Blue";
 $("#select-choice-2 option:contains(" + theText + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

in above function value would be either a,b,c not **Thermoplastic**

so

```
function selectTransport(value){
 if(value==="c")
 {
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using jquery you can easily do you task, below is the code:

```
    var ddlArray= new Array();
var ddl = document.getElementById('tierFormulaBase');
for (i = 0; i < ddl.options.length; i++) {
   ddlArray[i] = ddl .options[i].text;
}

$("#tierChangeType").change(function (e) {
    var e = document.getElementById("tierChangeType");
    var selectedValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var selectedText = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

    document.getElementById('tierFormulaBase').innerHTML = "";
    var src = document.getElementById('tierFormulaBase');
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    if(selectedValue == 1)
    {
         opt.text = ddlArray[0];
        opt.value = selectedValue;
    }else if (selectedValue == 2)
    {
         opt.text = ddlArray[1];
        opt.value = selectedValue;
    }
    else if (selectedValue == 3)
    {
         opt.text = ddlArray[2];
        opt.value = selectedValue;
    }
    src.add(opt);
 });
```

for live demo and more info go through this link:[click here to view code](http://www.jkstack.com/2013/07/how-to-change-second-dropdownlist-value.html)